# testing "cache not flushed to main memory" for my ring-buffer implementation

Tags: c++, multithreading

**upd** to reflect lattest suggestion made `curWriteNum` volatile, rearranged `pool.Commit();` with `std::cout`

I've created one-reader one-writer ring-buffer (class ArrayPool in example).
I like it but i'm afraid if I can face a problem when one (reader) thread do not see fresh values because another thread is running on another CPU and use another cache or something like that.

I've created test program. It creates 100 threads so I assume they must be distributed on all available processors more or less.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

template<class T> class ArrayPool
{
public:
    ArrayPool() {
    };

    ~ArrayPool(void) {
    };

    bool IsEmpty() {
        return curReadNum == curWriteNum;
    }

    T* TryGet()
    {
        if (curReadNum == curWriteNum)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
        T* result = &storage[curReadNum & MASK];
        ++curReadNum;
        return result;
    }

    T* Obtain() {
        return &storage[curWriteNum & MASK];
    }

    void Commit()
    {
        ++curWriteNum;
        if (curWriteNum - curReadNum > length)
        {
            std::cout <<
                "ArrayPool curWriteNum - curReadNum > length! " <<
                curWriteNum << " - " << curReadNum << " > " << length << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    static const uint32_t length = 65536;
    static const uint32_t MASK = length - 1;
    T storage[length];
    volatile uint32_t curWriteNum;
    uint32_t curReadNum;
};

struct myStruct {
    int value;
};

ArrayPool<myStruct> pool;

void ReadThread() {
    myStruct* entry;
    while(true) {
        while ((entry = pool.TryGet()) != NULL) {
            std::cout << entry->value << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

void WriteThread(int id) {
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(1000 * id);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);

    myStruct* storage = pool.Obtain();
    storage->value = id;
    pool.Commit();
    std::cout << "Commited value! " << id << std::endl;
}


int main( void )
{
    boost::thread readThread = boost::thread(&ReadThread);
    boost::thread writeThread;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        writeThread = boost::thread(&WriteThread, i);
    }
    writeThread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to run this program on 2 * Xeon E5 server and everything is fine, every value was catched:

```
...
Commited value! 19
19
Commited value! 20
20
Commited value! 21
21
Commited value! 22
22
Commited value! 23
23
Commited value! 24
24
Commited value! 25
25
Commited value! 26
26
    ....
```

Also in Process Explorer I can see how number of threads decrease from ~101 to 1.
Does it mean that my ArrayPool class is fine and it is not possible to face any such kind of problems on modern Intel processors? If it's possible to reproduce "cache-memory" problem then how to do that?

Comment: You do not get much benefit have a considerable number of threads that processors. In fact your performance gets degraded due to context switching.

Comment: @EdHeal i know but that's the point, i try to "break" my program, trying to make it NOT working.

Comment: A few mutexes would not go amiss. What is the point of breaking it?

Comment: @EdHeal it's for low-latency HFT trading application. i prefer lock-free code when possible

Comment: And risk inconsistent data? Good luck to those spending their cash on your trading system. I, for one, hope it is not my pension manager

Comment: @EdHeal can you prove that it is a risk of inconsistency?

Comment: try running `TryGet` in parallel. Could return the same `result` twice but decrement the counter twice (you are using `curReadNum`) in multiple threads

Comment: @EdHeal i never run TryGet in parallel as I have one-reader one-writer. I have a lot of threads in example because I want to "occupy" as much CPU's and CPU's cores as possible. But even in this example I never run TryGet in parallel as this is not supported by design.

Comment: Well you using `curWrite` in parallel. That needs to be protected

Comment: @EdHeal now I declared `curWrite` as volatile, not sure if this is enough

Answer (score 1):

First of all, no this program is not safe. It might be true that you cannot reproduce cache ordering issues on your particular compiler and architecture combination. In particular note that this is not only about your processor cache. In theory your compiler is allowed to swap assignment operations. So what can you do to increase your risk?

- Try different compilers at different (most often high) optimization levels. For instance, if I compile with `x86_64-linux-gnu-g++-4.8 -O3`, the reader misses all values. Most likely the compiler inlines the `TryGet` and notices that the loop body does not affect the condition. It can therefore cache the result of the condition in a register value. To avoid this behavior, you would need to mark one of the variables in the condition as `volatile`.
- Try different processor architectures (for different cache behaviour).
- Between your `Commit` and the actual value write, there is a system call going on. It takes considerable amount of time. Swap those operations.

Even if you want to go without locking, you will need at the bare minimum read barriers and write barriers. Have a look at [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/573436/) to get a grasp of the complexity and for learning a library that will help you writing lock-free algorithms.

Comment: thanks, i find you suggestions helpful. I need to modify program so that I introduce as less latency as possible but still guarantee that it will work on modern Intel processor in case of one-reader one-writer. Do you think I should declare both `curWriteNum` and `curReadNum` `volatile` or it's enough to declare only one of them as `volatile`? If I declare these fields `volatile` will I have working `queue` for one-reader/one-writer on modern Intel CPU?

Comment: Using `volatile` declarations is definitely not enough. It just fixes the most apparent error. You *do* need "memory barrier" operations, which can be both OS and CPU specific. Please use the [urcu](http://lttng.org/urcu) library if you do need speed. Note that in certain configurations urcu can achieve zero overhead.

Comment: yes I guess I probably need memory barrier somewhere that's why I asked the question, but I can't understand where and why I need a barrier so waiting when someone can help :) Also it's interesting if I insert memeory barrier can i NOT declare field as volatile.

Comment: also updated my example in the question to reflect your suggestions